# Coding logic for 4x3 slot machine Kotlin -> Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, logic, slots

I just want to start off with, be gentle with me please. This is all new to me and I'm still learning.

I'm creating a slot game app, but I'm struggling with the coding on it recognizing patterns for winning lines. Here is the setup of my slot placement images:

```
|---reel1_symbol1--- reel2_symbol1--- reel3_symbol1--- reel4_symbol1---|
|---reel1_symbol2--- reel2_symbol2--- reel3_symbol2--- reel4_symbol2---|
|---reel1_symbol3--- reel2_symbol3--- reel3_symbol3--- reel4_symbol3---|
```

I attempted to teach it winning patterns with this block of code:

```
private fun checkWinningCombinations(finalSymbols: List<List<String>>): Long {
        // Define the winning patterns
        val winningPatterns = listOf(
            // Single-line winning patterns
            //Line of 2
            listOf(
                listOf("X", "X", "O", "O"),
                listOf("O", "O", "O", "O"),
                listOf("O", "O", "O", "O")
            ),
            listOf(
                listOf("O", "O", "O", "O"),
                listOf("X", "X", "O", "O"),
                listOf("O", "O", "O", "O")
            ),
            listOf(
                listOf("O", "O", "O", "O"),
                listOf("O", "O", "O", "O"),
                listOf("X", "X", "O", "O")
            ),
            //Line of 3
            listOf(
                listOf("X", "X", "X", "O"),
                listOf("O", "O", "O", "O"),
                listOf("O", "O", "O", "O")
            ),
            listOf(
                listOf("O", "O", "O", "O"),
                listOf("X", "X", "X", "O"),
                listOf("O", "O", "O", "O")
            ),
            listOf(
                listOf("O", "O", "O", "O"),
                listOf("O", "O", "O", "O"),
                listOf("X", "X", "X", "O")
            ),
            //Line of 4
            listOf(
                listOf("X", "X", "X", "X"),
                listOf("O", "O", "O", "O"),
                listOf("O", "O", "O", "O")
            ),
            listOf(
                listOf("O", "O", "O", "O"),
                listOf("X", "X", "X", "X"),
                listOf("O", "O", "O", "O")
            ),
            listOf(
                listOf("O", "O", "O", "O"),
                listOf("O", "O", "O", "O"),
                listOf("X", "X", "X", "X")
            ),
            // Multi-line winning patterns
            listOf(
                listOf("X", "O", "O", "X"),
                listOf("O", "X", "X", "O"),
                listOf("O", "O", "O", "O")
            ),
            listOf(
                listOf("X", "O", "O", "O"),
                listOf("O", "X", "O", "O"),
                listOf("O", "O", "O", "O")
            ),
            listOf(
                listOf("O", "O", "O", "X"),
                listOf("O", "X", "O", "O"),
                listOf("X", "O", "O", "O")
            ),
            listOf(
                listOf("O", "O", "O", "O"),
                listOf("O", "X", "X", "O"),
                listOf("X", "O", "O", "X")
            )
        )
        val symbolMapping = mapOf(
            "cherryblossom_girl1" to "X",
            "cherryblossom_tower" to "X",
            "cherryblossom_cat" to "X",
            "cherryblossom_komono" to "X",
            "cherryblossom_rice_chopsticks" to "X",
            "cherryblossom_flower" to "X",
            "cherryblossom_fan" to "X",
            "cherryblossom_umbrella" to "X"
        )
        // Translate finalSymbols using the symbolMapping
        val translatedFinalSymbols = finalSymbols.map { row ->
            row.map { symbol ->
                symbolMapping[symbol] ?: ""
            }
        }
        // Iterate over each winning pattern and check if it matches the final symbols
        for (pattern in winningPatterns) {
            var matchCount = 0
            for (i in pattern.indices) {
                var matchFound = true
                for (j in pattern[i].indices) {
                    if (translatedFinalSymbols[i][j] != pattern[i][j]) {
                        matchFound = false
                        break
                    }
                }
                if (matchFound) {
                    matchCount++
                }
            }
            if (matchCount == pattern.size) {
                return calculatePayout(pattern[0]) // Payout based on the first symbol of the pattern
            }
        }

        // Return 0 if no winning combination is found
        return 0
    }
    // Function to calculate the payout based on the final symbols displayed
    private fun calculatePayout(finalSymbols: List<String>): Long {
        val symbolValues = mapOf(
            "cherryblossom_girl1" to 100L,
            "cherryblossom_tower" to 80L,
            "cherryblossom_cat" to 60L,
            "cherryblossom_komono" to 40L,
            "cherryblossom_rice_chopsticks" to 30L,
            "cherryblossom_flower" to 20L,
            "cherryblossom_fan" to 10L,
            "cherryblossom_umbrella" to 5L
        )

        var winAmount = 0L
        val winSymbols = mutableSetOf<String>()
        for (symbol in finalSymbols) {
            val value = symbolValues[symbol] ?: 0L
            if (value > 0) {
                winAmount += value
                winSymbols.add(symbol)
            }
        }

        // Determine the prize amount based on win symbols
        return when {
            winSymbols.size == 4 -> winAmount * 10L // Jackpot if all symbols are the same
            winSymbols.size >= 3 -> winAmount * 5L // High win if three or more symbols are the same
            winSymbols.size == 2 -> winAmount * 2L // Medium win if two symbols are the same
            else -> winAmount // Low win or no win
        }
    }
```

Here is the xml layer if it helps

```
<!-- res/layout/activity_cherryblossom_slotgame.xml -->

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.snggoeevee.slotswithfriends.HomeActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cherryblossomslot_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/cherryblossumslots_background" />

    <!-- Reel 1 -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/reel1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="first reel"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:src="@drawable/cherryblossom_reel1" />

    <!-- Reel 2 -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/reel2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="second reel"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:src="@drawable/cherryblossom_reel2" />

    <!-- Reel 3 -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/reel3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="third reel"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:src="@drawable/cherryblossom_reel3" />

    <!-- Reel 4 -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/reel4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="fourth reel"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:src="@drawable/cherryblossom_reel4" />

    <!-- First/Top Payline Row -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/imgs"
        android:layout_width="469dp"
        android:layout_height="181dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/reel1_symbol1"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/cherryblossom_cat" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/reel2_symbol1"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/cherryblossom_cat" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/reel3_symbol1"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="65dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            android:src="@drawable/cherryblossom_cat" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/reel4_symbol1"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/cherryblossom_cat" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Second/Middle Payline Row -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/imgs2"
        android:layout_width="485dp"
        android:layout_height="69dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgs"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/reel1_symbol2"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/cherryblossom_cat" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/reel2_symbol2"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/cherryblossom_cat" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/reel3_symbol2"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="65dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            android:src="@drawable/cherryblossom_cat" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/reel4_symbol2"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/cherryblossom_cat" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Third/Bottom Payline Row -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/imgs3"
        android:layout_width="486dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgs2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/reel1_symbol3"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/cherryblossom_cat" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/reel2_symbol3"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/cherryblossom_cat" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/reel3_symbol3"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="65dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            android:src="@drawable/cherryblossom_cat" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/reel4_symbol3"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/cherryblossom_cat" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cherryblossomslot_cover"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/cherryblossumslots_frameboarder2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/top_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="118dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/top_banner" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_bar"
        android:layout_width="865dp"
        android:layout_height="79dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/slots_spinbar" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonsLayout"
        android:layout_width="558dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="@+id/top_bar"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/usernameTextView"
            android:layout_width="197dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/empty_bar"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp"
            android:text="Username"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="19sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/coin_balance"
            android:layout_width="183dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/coin_balance_bar"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="coinbalance"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="19sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/star_balance"
            android:layout_width="183dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/star_balance_bar"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="starbalance"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottombuttonsLayout"
        android:layout_width="181dp"
        android:layout_height="74dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="@+id/bottom_bar">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/spinbutton"
            android:layout_width="183dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/spin_button" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Other UI elements can be added on top of the background if needed -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totalbidTextView"
        android:layout_width="213dp"
        android:layout_height="83dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/totalbid_bar"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="totalbid"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/raisebid"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/totalbid_bar_plus"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="160dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/lowerbid"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/totalbidbar_minus"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

There are 8 different symbols that I will have spin. They are doing the spinning animation currently, so I'm happy there. I mean the animation isn't perfect, but for my first slot machine, I'm happy enough. However it's not recognizing any winning patterns. I think it's because the way I tried to code it, but I can't figure out how to fix it... If someone can fix this code for me and show me what I did wrong, I'd greatly appreciate it! TIA! <3 If you need more info, just me know!

---

I've tried to alter this section multiple times:

```
for (pattern in winningPatterns) {
            var matchCount = 0
            for (i in pattern.indices) {
                var matchFound = true
                for (j in pattern[i].indices) {
                    if (translatedFinalSymbols[i][j] != pattern[i][j]) {
                        matchFound = false
                        break
                    }
                }
                if (matchFound) {
                    matchCount++
                }
            }
            if (matchCount == pattern.size) {
                return calculatePayout(pattern[0]) // Payout based on the first symbol of the pattern
            }
        }

        // Return 0 if no winning combination is found
        return 0
    }
```

I think this is where my problem is, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: While I don't understand the game completely I think one flaw is while mapping finalSymbols to translatedFinalSymbols. It should be assigning "O" when not matching:
val translatedFinalSymbols = finalSymbols.map { row ->
        row.map { symbol ->
            symbolMapping[symbol] ?: "O"
        }
    }

Comment: Also, while calling calculatePayout(). Why are you only passing the first list of pattern? Nevertheless pattern contains "O" and "X" and not the "cherryblossom_XXXX". They will never match.

Comment: @Saty I appreciate the input. I tried the "val translatedFinalSymbols = finalSymbols.map { row -> row.map { symbol -> symbolMapping[symbol] ?: "O" " change, but it didn't work. I'm trying a new pattern now, although not much luck. I'll try again tomorrow. ty